# PHP incredibly slow since upgrading macOS to 10.14 Mojave?

Tags: macos, terminal, upgrade, mojave, php

Since I upgraded my Mac to Mojave 10.14, I noticed PHP is incredibly slow.

When I do this from the terminal:

`php -v`

It takes about 4-5 seconds before showing the version number, which is:
 `PHP 7.1.13 (cli) (built: Feb  1 2018 13:38:42) ( NTS )`

Is there a way to fix this? And, perhaps upgrade to the latest PHP (currently 7.2) while I'm at it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced a similar issue on Mojave update, I was able to fix it by updating `/etc/hosts` file with

```
::1             localhost YouMacName.local
127.0.0.1       localhost YouMacName.local
```

You can get `YourMacName.local` by running in terminal:

```
$ hostname
```

I hope it helps you